# how to import your library to android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

i would like to import my own library file to android studio..

So what i have done is the library module is correctly marked as library

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

the manifest of login module has the following

```
package="com.quid.loginmodule"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
```

and the dependency in the build.gradle file is as follows

```
compile 'com.quid.loginmodule:1.1'
Error:Failed to resolve: com.quid.loginmodule:1:
```

so my question is how should i add the library to my gradle??

Comment: Hi Alvin, can we have chat. so that i can tell you all procedure as it is little bit long procedure to add library in studio.

Comment: what is your library file

Comment: @RishiPaul please access the following link http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/78747/how-to-import-your-library-to-android-studio?tab=general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution For The problem is given in Chat. May be It will help You.

[Importing Library Android Studio](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78747/how-to-import-your-library-to-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

1. In the project view, right-click the dependent module and select Open > Module Settings.Right-click the plus icon to add a new dependencies.

2.If you are adding references to multiple libraries, you can set their relative priority (and merge order) by selecting a library and using the Up and Down controls. The tools merge the referenced libraries with your application starting from lowest priority (bottom of the list) to highest (top of the list). If more than one library defines the same resource ID, the tools select the resource from the library with higher priority. The application itself has highest priority and its resources are always used in preference to identical resource IDs defined in libraries.

3.Use the Scope drop-down to select how the dependency will be applied.Click Apply to create the dependency and OK to close the Project Structure window.

Source : developer.android. com